# How to find the unicode combinations?

Tags: javascript

I have some emojis like (‍ ‍     )this. And I'm adding a `span` to this each and every emoji. I have a processing code to convert it to a `span` here is the function which will convert to the `span`

```
emojiSpan = function (emojis) {
  if (!emojis)
    return;
  try {
    let emojiSpan;
    var unicodeMatch = /([\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\u2694-\u2697]|\uD83E[\uDD10-\uDD5D])/g;
    if (emojis.match(unicodeMatch)) {
      emojis.match(unicodeMatch).filter(function (unicode) {
        if (unicode.trim().length === 1) return emojis;
        emojiSpan = _getEmojiSpan(unicode);
        emojis = Utility.replaceAll(emojis, unicode.trim(), emojiSpan);
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error while parsing emoji", error.stack);
  }
  return emojis;
};

var _getEmojiSpan = function(emoji){
if(!emoji)
  return;
return `<span class="emojiNative">${emoji}</span>`;  
}
```

Here, the input is ‍ ‍   and I'm getting output like

```html
<span class="emojiNative"></span>‍
<span class="emojiNative">
  <span class="emojiNative"></span>
</span>
<span class="emojiNative"></span>‍
<span class="emojiNative">
  <span class="emojiNative"></span>
</span>
<span class="emojiNative">
  <span class="emojiNative"></span>
</span>
<span class="emojiNative"></span>
<span class="emojiNative">
  <span class="emojiNative"></span>
</span>
<span class="emojiNative"></span>
```

The emojis are getting separated. How can I get the exact emojis? please help me.

The expected output is

```html
<span class="emojiNative">‍</span>‍
<span class="emojiNative">‍</span>
<span class="emojiNative"></span>
<span class="emojiNative">  </span>
```

Comment: Not clear what the issue is. What exactly is separating? What output do you expect? How do you input to your method inside your example?

Comment: I added the expeted output as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emoji that "merge" into a single one, such as the male/female programmer, are separated by a Zero-Width Joiner U+200D. You can extend to regex to look like `[emoji](?:\u200D[emoji])*` to add support for combined emoji.

As for the flags, those are made by having two Regional Indicators spelling out the country code. These indicators are in a fixed range, so when you find that range you can check if there are two of them, and keep them together if so:

```
(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDFF]){2}
```

Make sure this goes *before* the other `\uD83C` segment of your regex.

```js
emojiSpan = function (emojis) {
  if (!emojis)
    return;
  try {
    var unicodeMatch = /(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDFF]){2}|(?:[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\u2694-\u2697]|\uD83E[\uDD10-\uDD5D])(?:\u200D(?:[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\u2694-\u2697]|\uD83E[\uDD10-\uDD5D]))*/g;
    emojis = emojis.replace(unicodeMatch, '<span class="emojiNative">$&</span>');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error while parsing emoji", error.stack);
  }
  return emojis;
};

var _getEmojiSpan = function(emoji){
if(!emoji)
  return;
return `<span class="emojiNative">${emoji}</span>`;  
}
document.body.innerHTML += emojiSpan("‍ ‍  ");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it was working fine and I need one small help my regexp is not finding some the emojis in this url https://missive.github.io/emoji-mart/. Can you provide a regexp which will find all the emojis. please help me

Comment: Since emoji are always being added... no, sorry. Not for free, anyways.

Comment: Hi, How I can the `unicodeMatch` with this regexp `/[\u{1f300}-\u{1f5ff}\u{1f900}-\u{1f9ff}\u{1f600}-\u{1f64f}\u{1f680}-\u{1f6ff}\u{2600}-\u{26ff}\u{2700}-\u{27bf}\u{1f1e6}-\u{1f1ff}\u{1f191}-\u{1f251}\u{1f004}\u{1f0cf}\u{1f170}-\u{1f171}\u{1f17e}-\u{1f17f}\u{1f18e}\u{3030}\u{2b50}\u{2b55}\u{2934}-\u{2935}\u{2b05}-\u{2b07}\u{2b1b}-\u{2b1c}\u{3297}\u{3299}\u{303d}\u{00a9}\u{00ae}\u{2122}\u{23f3}\u{24c2}\u{23e9}-\u{23ef}\u{25b6}\u{23f8}-\u{23fa}]/gu`

Comment: That regex uses Unicode code points, which you would have to convert into UTF-16 surrogate pairs.

Comment: Yes. But, it is finding almost all the unicodes which I have